# BackHandler.exitApp app is staying minimized on resume showing old page

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Having an issue with react native `BackHandler` android, I am trying to get my app to close when pressing back on the "home" screen.

```
  onBackPress() {
       BackHandler.exitApp();
       return false;

    }

    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this._onBackPress = this.onBackPress.bind(this);
    }
```

scene setup:

```
const Scenes = Actions.create(
  <Scene key="root">
    <Scene key="setup" component={SetupContainer} title="setup" hideNavBar></Scene>
    <Scene key="home" component={HomeContainer} title="home" hideNavBar></Scene>
  </Scene>
);
```

however, the app is simply minimizing, and **when the user selects the app again, it will show the previous page (Setup) which is meant to only be accessed once.**

is there anyway around this I want to actually destroy the app so that it cannot be resumed.

Comment: Yes it's a bug in 'react-native-router-flux' library. As you'll see [here](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+back), many people are having issues with the back button behavior of exiting an app (which was a breeze in native android). I have been trying hacks for the same issue for the past 2 days, but to no success. I also made a native module to invoke "Activity.finish()" when back button is pressed, but even then the app resumes from the same screen, instead of restarting with the Splash Screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this solution.
To exit from the app, I used a Native Module which basically "kills" the app so that it can be restarted like an iOS app, instead of resuming from previous screen.

In my native code, I am calling  -

```
     @ReactMethod
  public void finishAndroidActivity(int x) {
    Log.d("MainActivity","finishAndroidActivity");
    Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
    //Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), "Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (activity != null) {
        Log.d("Received Value =", String.valueOf(x));
        if(x==1)
        {
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        }
        else
            activity.onBackPressed();
    }
  }
```

to exit the process.

From my Javascript code, I'm passing an Integer value depending on which screen I want to exit from each time back button is pressed (in the reducer function) -

```
const reducerCreate = params => {
    const defaultReducer = new Reducer(params);
    return (state, action) => {
        if (action.type === 'Navigation/BACK') {
            if (Actions.currentScene === 'Dashboard') {
                MyModuleExitApp.finishAndroidActivity(1);
            }
        }
        return defaultReducer(state, action);
    };

};
```

This is working fine as the app is now killed and restarted from the Splash Screen.